# Uncheck value of Liferay Edit control by default for all users

Tags: liferay-6, edit-control

I have hidden liferay edit control by using way like....

```
$theme.include($body_top_include) 

#if ($permissionChecker.isOmniadmin())

#dockbar()
#end
```

it will hide doc bar for all users except Admin.

But I am unable to hide portlet controls icons like plus,minus, close portlet icon.
As we know these icons will not displayed if we uncheck value of edit control checkbox.

Liferay might be storing that edit conrol checkbox value on/off in their session.

So how can we uncheck that value by default for all users?

In short I want set value of edit control checkbox by default false for users .

Comment: Are you trying to impact all roles, or just certain ones?  It looks like you simply want non-admins to not have access to page edit controls, which is best accomplished with the permissions system. The (default) regular User role on a given site, for example, doesn't see "Toggle Edit Controls" at all in the dockbar, and doesn't see portlet configuration controls in a portlet's chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the custom- and update-permissions for this page for "User", "Power User" and "Site Member" role.

Comment: I have tried in this way also, but  it didn't worked.Actually I am creating a site and assigning a site template to organization programitically.

Comment: If this permissions are removed, than only admin can see the portlet control buttons.

Comment: Yes ,you are correct, but Here I have already created a site template , and Also I have given permissions to only owner of site template (so owner will be admin(test@liferay.com)which creates site template), and then I am creating a organization and assigning this site template to this newly created organization. And I am getting value of edit control checkbox as true, which should be false permanently. How can I set it to false so no organization user will be able to see controls like close and.....other 2 options.